# Create many buffers, name properly, silently

Tags: buffers, auto-save

I am trying to avoid using the desktop save mode 1 option in my `.emacs` file.

We sudo a shared service account, so my buffers may differ from my colleagues buffers.

I launch Emacs from GNU/Linux with `emacs -nw` (as the `sudo`'d user) and then I start creating my buffers.
We have a monthly machine restart.  I do not mind losing my history, but it would be cool if I could save everything and just re-launch that.

If I cannot simply save / relaunch the save, then I'd like to know how to create ~20 buffers by executing a file (if possible).

Also, once I launch a buffer - is it possible to also run commands automatically after the launch?

Comment: I'm not sure of fully understand what you're asking exactly, but sounds like a custom configuration of `recentf-mode` to me.

Comment: Basically after I do:
emacs -nw

It start a shell and have 4 buffers.

then I create 20 buffers.

Let's call them buffer a-t
C-u M-x shell <RET> 
a <RET>

then do that for b-t

I don't want to do that manually and would like the system to do that for me.

Once that is done, it would be nice if I could issue a couple of commands per buffer, specific to that buffer. (that is not a requirement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could automate the opening of those 20 buffers and associate them with shells with something like this called from your init file (code for ilustrative purposes only):

```lisp
(defun twenty-buffers()
  "Create 20 buffers and associate them to a shell process."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer-names (list "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t")))
    (dolist (item buffer-names)
      (shell (get-buffer-create item)))))
```

You can send input to each shell programmatically just switching to the desired buffer and inserting the text for the command at the end of the buffer this way:

```lisp
(insert "ls -lah")
(comint-send-input)
```

On saving the buffers there are various options,but probably I'd go with `run-at-time` and a function similar to twenty-buffers shown above.

Comment: I thought I replied to this comment shortly after you posted it.  The 'twenty-buffers' works great!.   Thanks so much. Now I'd like to add additional tasks after buffer creation: 

During buffer creation, I'd like:
If buffer = 'a', run shell command '. set asdf-a'
elseif buffer = 'b', run shell command '.set asdf-b'
etc

can this be done?

Comment: you could simply `(switch-to-buffer item)` after creating the shell then insert the proper command the way shown in the second code block. Shell commands could be a list of strings, one by shell, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply set `desktop-dirname` to something non-conflicting. Then you can safely use `desktop` as normal.